# Flattening Nested JSON Structures in PySpark Streaming DataFrame

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working with a PySpark streaming DataFrame containing three columns: `Time`, `System`, and `Data`. The `Data` column holds nested JSON structures in string format. Here's a simplified example:

| Time | System | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-06T05:59:46.230+00:00 | com1 | {"A": {"::a": "abc-01"}, "B": {"::a": "string1"}, "C": {"::a": "{"ABC":"123","PQR":"456"}"}} |

This is just an illustration. The actual `Data` column can have multiple keys. Here, I showed three keys 'A', 'B', and 'C' for simplicity. Also, "::a" is just a dummy key.

I need to flatten out the data to create a resulting DataFrame like this:

| Time | System | A | B | C_ABC | C_PQR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-06T05:59:46.230+00:00 | com1 | abc-01 | string1 | 123 | 456 |

To achieve this, I need to perform two tasks:

1. Parsing keys in the Data field as separate columns. The corresponding values are under the structure {Key}.::a. For example, I want to parse columns for keys 'A', 'B' with values 'abc-01', 'string1'.
2. For keys like 'C' with further nested JSON structures as their values, explode these columns: For example, for the key 'C', I want to explode it into columns by appending the child key to the parent key with an underscore like 'C_ABC' and 'C_PQR' with values '123' and '456' respectively.

I attempted the following code:

```
df.withColumn('data', from_json(df.data, json_schema))\
  .select('time', 'system', 'data.*')
```

where json_schema is defined as:

```
json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", StructType([StructField("::c", StringType())]), True),
    StructField("B", StructType([StructField("::c", StringType())]), True),
    StructField("C", StructType([StructField("::c", StringType())]), True),
])
```

Output:

| Time | System | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-06T05:59:46.230+00:00 | com1 | {"::a": "abc-01"} | {"::a": "string1"} | {"::a": "{"ABC":"123","PQR":"456"}"}} |

However, the result adds the whole nested JSON object as the value of the flattened columns, which is not the desired outcome.

Additionally, when I modified the schema to handle further nesting:

```
json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", StructType([StructField("::c", StringType())]), True),
    StructField("B", StructType([StructField("::c", StringType())]), True),
    StructField("C", StructType([StructField("::c", StructType([\
                             StructField('ABC', StringType(), True),\
                             StructField('PQR', StringType(), True),\)]), True),
    ])
])
```

It shows NULL values in the C column:

| Time | System | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-06T05:59:46.230+00:00 | com1 | {"::a": "abc-01"} | {"::a": "string1"} | NULL |

How can I correctly parse and flatten the nested JSON structures in the Data column while handling further nesting? I'm new to pyspark and would appreciate any help.